# Internet Explorer 6 Mobile Scrollbar Rendering Problems

Tags: mobile, internet-explorer-6, scrollbar

I have a web application running on internet explorer 6 mobile, and I've noticed that the rendering of scroll bars is inconsistent. For example, if you take a regular html select (with lots of entries) and expand it, the scroll bar renders in a slim, black-colored way, but if you have an overflowing div, you get a wide, old windows-style scroll. Do you know of a way to force the rendering to the select-style one? (screenshots follow)

[image]